# How Would I print A Vector of Floats?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to make a vector to contain three floats, one representing x, one for y, and one for z. So for the moment, I added random integers into the vector, and now I'm trying to print it so I can see the position values, but I can't seem to print it right. Could someone please look over this code to see what I could be missing? Thank you

Character.h

```
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Character
{
  public:
    Character();

    void printCharacter();

    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    int healthPoints=rand() % 100;
    vector<float> position;
    float f = rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1) + 12 + (rand() % 4);
};
```

Character.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Character.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

void Character::printCharacter() 
{
  cout << "Enter First Name" << endl;
  cin >> firstName;
  cout << "Enter Last Name" << endl;
  cin >> lastName;
  cout << endl;
  cout << firstName << " " << lastName << ": " << endl;
  cout << "Health: " << healthPoints << endl;
  cout << "Position: "<<endl;

  for (auto i=0; i<position.size(); i++) 
  { 
    srand(time(NULL));
    position.push_back(f);
    cout << position[i] << endl;
  }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Character.h"

int main()
{
  Character* ch = new Character;

  ch->printCharacter();
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post some compilable code. And say exactly what you mean by " I can't seem to print it right"

Comment: I added the rest of the code. The floats just won't output in the .exe window.

Comment: `class Character(){` -- Where in any C++ book or tutorial do you see a class defined with parentheses `()` like that?

Comment: I didn't copy and paste the code, I just typed essentially what I needed. It was just a typo on here.

Comment: @Damonlaws *I didn't copy and paste the code, I just typed essentially what I needed* -- Do *not* type in the code.  Actually copy and paste the exact code in the edit window.  If you get a compiler error, and you paste fake code, that wastes everyone's time.

Comment: Unrelated: `Character* ch = new Character;` could be `Character ch;` and save you from some some memory management headaches that you are completely ignoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a range-based for loop:

```
for (auto posit : position)
{
    cout << posit << endl;
}
```

Now, I'm pretty new to coding myself, but here's my attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Character
{
private:
    vector<float> position;
    float f;

public:
    Character()
    {
        populateCharacter(5);
    }

    //I separated out the push and print as separate functions
    void populateCharacter(int vectorSize)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < vectorSize; i++){
            f = rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1) + 12 + (rand() % 4);
            position.push_back(f);
        }
    }

    void printCharacter()
    {
        cout << "Position: "<<endl;

        for (auto posit : position)
        {
            cout << posit << endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Character* ch = new Character;

    ch->printCharacter();
    delete ch;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
position.reserve(3);
for (int i=0; i<position.size(); i++)
```

`reserve()` does not change the size of the `vector`.  So your `vector` stays empty, and the loop never runs.

Also, you should call `srand()` only once, and generate the random value in the loop unless you want them all to be the same.

---

```
float f = rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1) + 12 + (rand() % 4);
```

`rand()` returns an `int` smaller than `RAND_MAX`, so the division yields `0`. 
 Hence you can replace that expression with :

```
float f = 12 + rand() % 4;
```

Since the right hand side is an `int`, f is going to be `12.0`, `13.0`, `14.0` or `15.0`.

---

You could implement the constructor like this:

```
Character::Character()
: position(3)
{
}
```

Comment: then would I set up the declaration like this?  vector<float> position(3);
But With that, I get the error 'expected a type identifier'

Comment: @Damonlaws, Are you sure ?  What compiler are you using ?

Comment: I'm using MSVC for visual studio 2017

Comment: @Damonslaws, there is nothing wrong with a declaration like `vector<float> position(3);`.  You must have other problems.

Comment: @Damonlaws -- Now do you see the issue of posting incorrect code that you're not actually compiling?  It now becomes a guessing game on what you're really trying to compile.

Comment: It's not showing me any other problems. Just that one error.

Comment: @Damonlaws That one error could be caused by other lines being wrong.

Comment: @Damonlaws, Update your question to include the actual code you are using.

Comment: @Damonlaws Better still, pick one bug and build an example program that contains the bug, the whole bug, and nothing but the bug. If isolating the bug down to the bare essentials doesn't show you how to fix it, ask a question about that

Comment: That compiles, but it doesn't link because you declared `Character::Character()` but didn't implement it.

Comment: @Damonlaws, I updated my answer to include the constructor.